# Excel vba sql: Syntax error in date inside query string

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to get some data with sql-filter `WHERE` inside Excel Macros.
But I get some errors with data-types:

```
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

Dim Value As Date
Value = .Range("B4").Value ' 30.10.2020

sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE DateTime = #" & Format(Value, "dd\.mm\.yyyy") & "#"
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql) 'here I get error
```

DateTime cells have format "Date". I get Run-time error `Syntax error in date in query expression 'DateTime = #30.10.2020'`.

Original file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNoJGyvSLtIosskXVNTKTsLXrksmE_Oc/view?usp=sharing).

What am I doing wrong with format?

Comment: have you tried Format(Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")?

Comment: Yes, the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization using the [ADO Command object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) and specify your input parameter as `adDate` type. Also, usually, proper dates are separated by hyphens and not periods between date parts (day, month, and year). But your system region/locale can be different assuming the cell is not a `Custom` format.

```vb
Dim cn As Object, cmd As Object, rs As Object
Dim output As String, sql As String
Dim dt As Date
Const adCmdText As Integer = 1, adDate As Integer = 7, adParamInput As Integer = 1

'dt = .Range("B4").Value                              ' IF REGION USES PERIODS IN DATES
dt = CDate(Replace(.Range("B4").Value, ".", "-"))     ' IF REGION USES HYPHENS IN DATES

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" _
                        & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" _
                        & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK ? PLACEHOLDER
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE DateTime = ?"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = cn
  .CommandText = sql
  .CommandType = adCmdText

  ' BIND PARAM AND DEFINE TYPE AND LENGTH
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adDate, adParamInput, , dt)

  ' CREATE RECORDSET
  Set rs = .Execute
End With
```

Comment: for your code I get "Compile error: Expected: If or Select or Sub or Function ir Property or Type ir With or Enum or end of statement" on `End cmd`

Comment: I changed `End cmd` on `End With`. Now I have error with `.CommandType = adCmdText`: "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another"

Comment: Sorry for those syntax errors. Yes, it should be `End With` and because your are running late binding (not early binding) of ADO objects, the constants `adCmdText`, `adDate`, `adParamInput` are not known. So, you need to manually define their values. See `Constant` declaration at top.